# Intercepting the close window button (Tkinter window) throws an Tcl error

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I have a program that at some point opens a new window (filled with buttons and gizmo's for the user to select and play around with) that is defined as follows:

```
def window(self,master):
  def close(self):
    # change some variables
    self.destroy()
  top = self.top = Toplevel()
  # Several lines of buttons
  top.lift()
  top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",close(self))
```

I initially had a close button there that would wrap everything up nicely but I noticed that if the user used the standard 'X' in the corner of the window, this function obviously would not be called and that would give a lot of problems later on. I found out about the 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' suggestion from some other questions on this website but it gives me a rather strange error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1630, in wm_protocol
    'wm', 'protocol', self._w, name, command)
TclError: bad window path name ".33862072"
```

I assume that it somehow has gotten the wrong window ID and is unable to catch the event. My question is thus, is that true or not and secondly how should I continue to deal with this issue.

Comment: well how about `top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.close)`

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with `protocol`, but if it's anything like `bind`, then you're probably actually calling `close` on the last line, rather than registering it as a callback for `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`. The typical solution for registering functions that require arguments, is to wrap them in a lambda: `top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: close(self))`

Comment: @Kevin That completely slipped my mind, I feel like an idiot now :(

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine this line of code:

```
top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",close(self))
```

This line of code is saying "immediately call the function `close(self)`, and assign the result to the protocol handler. See the problem? It's immediately calling `close`, likely before `self` has been fully constructed. You don't want the function to be *called*, you want to pass in a *reference* to the function.

Make `close` be a method of `self` (rather than an embedded function) and change the call to `top.protocol` to look like this (note the lack of trailing parenthesis):

```
top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
```

If you prefer to keep the nested function, you can use lambda:

```
top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda window=self: close(window))
```